# Bitacora de una base de datos?

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Necesito elaborar un disparador que registre los insert, update, delete que pasen en cierta tabla. Para esto, tengo el siguiente código en el cual, dentro del trigger para insert que ya tengo definido, me salta un error en diciendo que el nombre de la columna "cveMov" no es valido. Ademas, quisiera saber si hay alguna recomendacion que me puedan dar para los otros triggers, para insert y delete

```
    /**Creando la base de datos Empresa*/
    create database Empresa
    go

    use Empresa
    go

    /*Creando las tablas de la base de datos*/
    create table Cargo(
    cveCargo smallint not null identity constraint cargo_pk primary key,
    cargo varchar(50) not null,
    salarioBase int not null
    )
    go

    create table Empleado(
    cveEmp smallint not null identity constraint empleado_pk primary key,
    nombres varchar(100) not null,
    apellidoPat varchar(50) not null,
    apellidoMat varchar(50) not null,
    email varchar(80) not null
    )
    go

    create table CargoEmpleado(
    cveCargo smallint not null constraint cveCargo_fk references Cargo(cveCargo),
    cveEmp smallint not null constraint cveEmp_fk references Empleado(cveEmp),
    constraint CargoEmpleado_pk primary key (cveCargo,cveEmp)
    )
    go


    /*CREACIÓN DE LA BASE DE DATOS PARA LA BITACORA DE MOVIMIENTOS*/
    create database Bitacora
    go

    use Bitacora
    go

    /*CREANDO LA TABLA PRA LA BITACORA DE MOVIMIENTOS*/
    create table Bitacora(
    cveMov int not null identity constraint bitacora_pk primary key, 
    fechaHora datetime not null,
    tipoMovimiento char(6) not null,
    tablaAfectada varchar(15) not null,
    usuario varchar(25) not null,
    host varchar(15) not null
    )
    go

    create table BitacoraDetalle(
    cveMov int not null constraint BitacoraDetalle_cveMov_FK references Bitacora(cveMov),
    cveMovDeta int not null identity,
    cveModificada int not null,
    constraint BitacoraDetalle_PK primary key (cveMov,cveModificada,cveMovDeta),
    campoAlterado varchar (50) not null,
    valorAnterior varchar (150) null,
    valorNuevo varchar (150) null
    )
    go

    /*CREANDO EL DISPARADOR*/
    Create Trigger tri_InsertCargo
    On Cargo
    After Insert
        As
    declare @fechahora datetime = getdate()
    declare @host varchar(50) =host_name()
    declare @usuario varchar(50) = system_user
    declare @movimiento char(6) = 'Insert'
    declare @tabla varchar(10) = 'Cargo'

    Insert into dbo.Bitacora (fechaHora,tipoMovimiento,tablaAfectada,usuario,host)
    Values (@fechahora,@movimiento,@tabla,@usuario,@host)

    declare @atributo1 varchar(15) ='cargo'
    declare @atributo2 varchar(15) ='salarioBase'
    declare @cargo varchar(50) = null
    declare @cargo1 varchar(50) = (Select cargo From INSERTED)
    declare @sueldo int = null
    declare @sueldo1 int = (Select salarioBase From INSERTED)
    declare @claveModificada smallint = (Select cveCargo From INSERTED)
    declare @cveMov int = (Select cveMov from INSERTED)

    Insert into dbo.BitacoraDetalle(cveMov,cveModificada,campoAlterado,valorAnterior,valorNuevo)
    Values (@cveMov,@claveModificada,@atributo1,@cargo,@cargo1)

    Insert into dbo.BitacoraDetalle (cveMov,cveModificada,campoAlterado,valorAnterior,valorNuevo)
    Values (@cveMov,@claveModificada,@atributo2,@sueldo,@sueldo1)
    Go
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

El trigger lo tienes definido para la tabla `Cargo`. De modo que solo puedes acceder a los campos definidos en esa tabla cuando haces referencia a la tabla temporal `inserted`. Como la tabla `Cargo` no tiene campo `cveMov`, por eso te da un error al tratar de acceder `Select cveMov from INSERTED`

Comment: Oh. gracias, de casualidad sabrás de que forma puedo hacer referencia a esa columna?

Comment: Lo que pides no tiene sentido. El trigger solo te da acceso a los datos a los que acabas de insertar, de la tabla `Cargo` en este caso. Solo puedes hacer referencia a las columnas de esa tabla. No puedes acceder a algo que no existe..

Answer (score 0):

Hay una forma de tomar datos de otra tabla usando un INNER JOIN pero yo lo tengo hecho para lo que es postgresql y es asi

```
DECLARE BEGIN
INSERT INTO public.logbook (boxnum, entrydatem, exitdatem, partnum) SELECT old.boxnumm, old.entrydate, old.exitdate, partnum
FROM public.market me INNER JOIN public.connection cp ON me.boxnumm = cp.boxnum
where cp.boxnum = old.boxnumm;
RETURN OLD;
END;
$insertar$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Podrias intentar hacerlo para lo que tu quieres